# Beautiful soup 'find_all' function doesn't seem to scrape "find_all('div', class_ = 'ais-infinite-hits ais-results-as-block')"

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape an Australian retailer "JB HI-FI".

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.jbhifi.com.au/?q=a&hPP=36&idx=shopify_products&p=1'
response = get(url)
print(response.text)
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
type(html_soup)`
movie_containers = html_soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'ais-infinite-hits ais-results-as-block')
print(type(movie_containers))
print(len(movie_containers))`
```

Then I just got 0 for the length. [But I can clearly see 'ais-infinite-hits ais-results-as-block' by using "inspect" from google chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAfRx.png)

Comment: I checked the link from your code, the class you are trying to access is not in the page. Can you confirm the link has said class?

Comment: there is no `ais-infinite-hits` if download the content of the url with curl or wget or httpie. browser does a lot more than you expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you looking to scrape, but here's it:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get(
    'https://www.jbhifi.com.au/?q=a&hPP=36&idx=shopify_products&p=1')

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll("h4", {'class': 'ais-hit--title product-tile__title'}):
    print(item.get_text(strip=True))
driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
Sony X8000G 65" 4K UHDAndroid LED TV
Dyson V11Absolute
Dyson Cyclone V10Animal+
GoPro Hero7 Silver 4KAction Cam
Apple Watch Series 3 38mm Space GreyAluminium Case GPS
Apple Watch Series 3 38mm SilverAluminium Case GPS
Apple iPhone XS Max 256GB (Space Grey)
Apple iPhone XS 256GB (Gold)
Apple iPhone XS 64GB (Silver)
Apple iPhone 8 64GB (Space Grey)
Apple iPhone 7 128GB (Black)
Apple iPhone 7 32GB (Black)
Apple iPhone 7 32GB (Rose Gold)
ASUS ROG Gaming Phone II with ROG Kunai Gamepad
Kapture KPT-890 Full HD Discreet Barrel Dash Camera with GPSand WiFi
LG B9 65" 4K UHDAI Smart OLED TV
Xbox One S 1TBAll-Digital Edition Console (Disc-free Gaming)
Apple Watch Series 5 44mm Space GreyAluminum Case GPS + Cellular
Apple iPhone 11 Pro 64GB (Space Grey)
Samsung Galaxy Note10+ 256GB (Aura Glow)
Apple MacBookAir 13-inch with Retina display 256GB (Gold) [2019]
AcerAspire 3A315-54-35CL 15.6" Laptop (128GB)
Apple Watch Series 5 44mm Space GreyAluminum Case GPS
Apple Watch Series 5 40mm GoldAluminum Case GPS + Cellular
Apple iPhone 8 128GB (Space Grey)
Apple iPhone 11 64GB (Red)
Samsung Galaxy Note10+ 256GB (Aura Black)
Samsung Galaxy TabA8" Wi-Fi 32GB (Black) [2019]
Razer ViperAmbidextrous Gaming Mouse
Apple MacBook Pro 13-inch with Touch Bar 512GB (Space Grey) [2019]
Apple MacBook Pro 13-inch with Touch Bar 256GB (Space Grey) [2019]
Sony X8000G 55" 4K UHDAndroid LED TV
Samsung GalaxyA20 32GB (Blue)
HP Pavilion X360 11-AP0000TU 11.6" HD 2-in-1 Touchscreen Laptop
Samsung GalaxyA50 64GB (Black)
Samsung GalaxyA70 128GB (White)
```

Comment: Are there any ways to accelerate scraping? For example, not including pictures from JB Hi-Fi. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by that ? Sorry I didn’t get you ?

Comment: At this rate I can scrape 1 website every 10 seconds. How can I make it faster? In additional, I don't really understand QHarr's code. It seems he is getting some specific files. What is it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need overhead of browser. You can mimic POST request page makes and grab the API key and id from a js file. I have left one header as it can help with avoiding being served cached results (server can ignore). You can likely decode the `data` and pass as actual json to make more readable.

```
import requests, re

r = requests.get('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0024/9803/5810/t/2/assets/vendors@layout.checkout@layout.theme@template.addresses@template.cart@template.page.contact@template.page.contactform@template.page.faq@template.page.store@template.page.storelocator@template.product.js?345913')
p_id = re.compile(r'app_id:"(.*?)"')
p_key = re.compile(r'search_api_key:"(.*?)"')
search_id = p_id.findall(r.text)[0]
api_key = p_key.findall(r.text)[0]
headers = {'If-Modified-Since': 'Fri, 04 Oct 2019 04:52:05 GMT'}
data = '{"requests":[{"indexName":"shopify_products","params":"query=a&hitsPerPage=36&maxValuesPerFacet=100&page=1&filters=(price%20%3E%200%20AND%20product_published%20%3D%201%20AND%20availability.displayProduct%20%3D%201)&facets=%5B%22facets.Price%22%2C%22facets.Category%22%2C%22facets.Brand%22%5D&tagFilters="}]}'
r = requests.post(f'https://vtvkm5urpx-3.algolianet.com/1/indexes/*/queries?x-algolia-agent=Algolia for JavaScript (3.35.1); Browser (lite); instantsearch.js 2.10.5; JS Helper (2.28.0)&x-algolia-application-id={search_id}&x-algolia-api-key={api_key}',  data=data)
print(r.json())
```

Loop over pages:

```
import requests, re

r = requests.get('https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0024/9803/5810/t/2/assets/vendors@layout.checkout@layout.theme@template.addresses@template.cart@template.page.contact@template.page.contactform@template.page.faq@template.page.store@template.page.storelocator@template.product.js?345913')
p_id = re.compile(r'app_id:"(.*?)"')
p_key = re.compile(r'search_api_key:"(.*?)"')
search_id = p_id.findall(r.text)[0]
api_key = p_key.findall(r.text)[0]
headers = {'If-Modified-Since': 'Fri, 04 Oct 2019 04:52:05 GMT'}

with requests.Session() as s:
    for page in range(1, 101):
        data = f'{{"requests":[{{"indexName":"shopify_products","params":"query=a&hitsPerPage=36&maxValuesPerFacet=100&page={page}&filters=(price%20%3E%200%20AND%20product_published%20%3D%201%20AND%20availability.displayProduct%20%3D%201)&facets=%5B%22facets.Price%22%2C%22facets.Category%22%2C%22facets.Brand%22%5D&tagFilters="}}]}}'
        #print(data)
        r = s.post(f'https://vtvkm5urpx-3.algolianet.com/1/indexes/*/queries?x-algolia-agent=Algolia for JavaScript (3.35.1); Browser (lite); instantsearch.js 2.10.5; JS Helper (2.28.0)&x-algolia-application-id={search_id}&x-algolia-api-key={api_key}',  data=data)
        print(r.json())
```

Comment: I were sure that you will post such answer :D you usually call the script source. the point is I'm usually run from `regex`

Comment: I'm so confused. Sorry I'm new to web scrapping. What is this website 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0024/9803/5810/t/2/assets/vendors@layout.checkout@layout.theme@template.addresses@template.cart@template.page.contact@template.page.contactform@template.page.faq@template.page.store@template.page.storelocator@template.product.js?345913'?

Comment: This is where the info on your page is actually coming from . You can see shopify at the end of your url. The uris I reference are a source js file for the page and the actual source and query used by the page to retrieve products.

Comment: Did you try running it?

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to scrape the entire JB HI-FI. 'https://www.jbhifi.com.au/?q=a&hPP=36&idx=shopify_products&p=1' with p ranges from 1 to 100. How can I find the json file for all of them?

Comment: Any suggestion on scrapping the entrie JB HI-FI?

Comment: you issue the same request in a loop changing the page=1 param in the POST body. Use range to iterate through required number of pages.